# Backbone Marionette Google Maps infowindow button event

Tags: google-maps, backbone.js, marionette

I know how to display an infoWindow, but I have a problem capturing the event from a button displayed there.

```
var view = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
    ...
    methodA: function(){
        me.showMapInfoWindow(marker, "Test popup<button onclick='methodB()'>Click me</button>")
        me.infoWindow.open(me.map, marker);
    },
    methodB: function(){
        console.log("test");
    }
}
```

When I click the button, I get an error when calling methodB saying it's not defined. I've tried with me.methodB, etc...but no luck there. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. At first glance, it looks like a badly formatted string...

Comment: Ok, I've updated the code to be more clear

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yo5b0mn9/1/) showing an InfoWindow populated with a DOM node, rather than a HTML string. This way, we can use jQuery to add a programmatic event to the DOM, which can access the current scope, as shown.

```
    var $infoWindow = $('<div>Test popup<button>Click me</button></div>');
    $infoWindow.find('button').click(_.bind(this.methodB, this));
    me.showMapInfoWindow(marker, $infoWindow.get(0));
    me.infoWindow.open(me.map, marker);
```

---

**Answer to First Question**

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yo5b0mn9/) showing an InfoWindow firing a global function. In this case I had to set the function to Window scope, though I believe this is due to the JSFiddle environment.

```
window.myFunction = function() {
    window.alert("function fired!");
}
```

...

```
var html = '<button onclick=\'myFunction()\'>Click me</button>';
```

if you want to debug the scope, I'd suggest using the [debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) statement:

```
var html = '<button onclick=\'debugger;\'>Click me</button>';
```

Comment: I know I can do it with a global method, but i don't want to do it

Comment: you've updated your example, now I see you want not only the function, but also the context of an object, I'll update the answer